# Angular: following mouse position on scroll

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an element following my mouse around the page on mousemove.  It works fine but when I scroll the page, the mouse does not follow, how do I fix it so that it follows it on scroll?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lg2p6f?file=src/app/app.component.html

HTML:

```
<div
  class="wrapper"
  (mouseenter)="enter()"
  (mousemove)="move($event)"
  (mouseleave)="leave()"
>
  <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
  <div class="sites-circle" [ngClass]="mouseMove ? 'onMove' : 'notMove'">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
  enter(source: string) {
    this.tooltip.classList.add('show');
  }

  mouseStopped() {
    this.mouseMove = false;
    console.log("mousemove: " + this.mouseMove);
  }

  move(e: { pageX: number; pageY: number }) {

    this.mouseMove = true;
    console.log("mousemove: " + this.mouseMove);

    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(this.mouseStopped, 300);

    const tooltipStyle = this.tooltip.style;

    tooltipStyle.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    tooltipStyle.top = e.pageY + 'px';
  }

  leave() {
    this.tooltip.classList.remove('show');
  }
```

CSS:

```
.sites-circle.onMove {
  transform: scale(3);
}
.sites-circle.notMove {
  transform: scale(1) !important;
}
```

Comment: Can try :- Add mouse events on documents than div. [Please see this link for more details](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-3-renderer2-listen-14c6fe052b59)

Comment: [is this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529807/mousemove-event-is-triggered-onscroll-even-when-mouse-was-not-moved-on-chrome)?

Comment: [Add scroll event and write some logic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977888/onscroll-event-triggers-function-in-angular4)  might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6728432/3623608), `we cannot get mouse current position on scroll we can just get how much it scrolled relative to last position`.

For your problem, this can be realized as follows ([here is your updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tu8vho?file=src/app/app.component.ts)):

1. Add a `(window:scroll)` listener to your `<div>`.

```
<div
  class="wrapper"
  (mouseenter)="enter()"
  (mousemove)="move($event)"
  (window:scroll)="onScroll($event)"
  (mouseleave)="leave()"
>
```

2. Hold the last position, e.g.:

```
lastPosition = {
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined,
};

...

// inside your move() function
this.lastPosition.x = e.pageX;
this.lastPosition.y = e.pageY;
```

3. Hold the last known "move" page offset:

```
lastMovePageOffset = {
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined,
};

...

// inside your move() function
this.lastMovePageOffset.y = window.pageYOffset;
```

4. Use the difference of the current scroll position and the last known page "move" page offset to calculate the new position:

```
onScroll(e: any) {
    if (this.lastPosition.y !== undefined) {
      let pageOffsetY = 0;
      if (this.lastMovePageOffset.y !== undefined) {
        pageOffsetY = window.pageYOffset - this.lastMovePageOffset.y;
      }
      this.tooltip.style.top = this.lastPosition.y + pageOffsetY + 'px';
    }
}
```

This can be handled similarly with the `x`-Position. The solution works as soon as the cursor is moved once before scrolling (caused by the general problem described in the first sentence).

Good luck!

Comment: this makes sense but I added some more paragraphs, and it looks like the behavior becomes erratic, the element doesn't follow the mouse when scrolling up at all, and when I start scrolling down, the element becomes behaving strange.  Is it the same for you?: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmwktc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: This was indeed a problem! I just edited my answer to take into account the last known move page offset (and also updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tu8vho?file=src/app/app.component.ts)). Please have a look at it.

Comment: Ah I see what you did, thanks!